# WinRT - How to add popups as tooltips when I click a gridview element

Tags: c#, xaml, popup, windows-store-apps

On a windows store app project, I have a `Gridview` that shows images of users inside a circle, I'm trying to do a popup that shows information of that user when I click on of the circles with the image.

It would look something like this.

[image]

How can I get the position of the item clicked, to know where the popup appears?
And how can I do different instances of the same popup with the different information?

Or is there a better solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Flyout x:Name="InfoFlyout">
        <TextBlock>Hello World!</TextBlock>
    </Flyout>
</Page.Resources>


<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Blue" PointerPressed="Ellipse_PointerPressed" FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout="{StaticResource InfoFlyout}" />
    <Ellipse Grid.Column="1" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Blue" PointerPressed="Ellipse_PointerPressed" FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout="{StaticResource InfoFlyout}" />
    <Ellipse Grid.Column="2" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Blue" PointerPressed="Ellipse_PointerPressed" FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout="{StaticResource InfoFlyout}" />
    <Ellipse Grid.Column="3" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Blue" PointerPressed="Ellipse_PointerPressed" FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout="{StaticResource InfoFlyout}" />
</Grid>
```

And add this event handler:

```
private void Ellipse_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    InfoFlyout.ShowAt(sender as FrameworkElement);
}
```

Comment: Yes that seems to work, just a matter of adjusting the poisitioning a bit. Thanks